# Summing values from database

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know how to sum values from database. I have a lot of task ids in my array `$alltas`. In database I need to sum all these tasks hours. I've tried doing this:

```
foreach ($alltas as $keyy => $values) {
    $totalh = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(task_log_hours) AS hours FROM dotp_task_log WHERE task_log_task = '$values'");
    $totalh = mysql_fetch_array($totalh);
}
```

`$values` is the id of task. Problem is that this script sums only for the same id. I need to sum all ids which array `$alltas` has. Is it possible? Database looks like:

```
task_id | task_hours
300     | 0.30
300     | 2.30
310     | 1
```

SO it should sum like 3.60. With my code it sums only with same id so 2.60. Please help

Comment: I think your are searching for `group by task_log_task`!

Comment: you are over-ridding the value again and again in the loop so you will never get   proper result

Comment: You use the same variable name `totalh` in the whole time. So the later one will cover the former one.

Answer (score 4):

change the query into this

```
"select sum(task_log_hours) as hours from dotp_task_log where task_id in (" . join(',',$alltas) . ")";
```

and this won't need any `foreach`.